# An efficient way to create a path to a value dynamically based on a given nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to accomplish the following and my current method is to use lists and if/else like the following:

```
for key in keys:
    if key in ["apple","banana"]:
      path = "fruits"
    elif key in ["cats","dogs", "cows"]:
      path = "animals"
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this path creation, incase I have more cases to check?

The keys are part of a document like so:

```
{
fruits:  { "apple" : 1, "banana": 2},
animals: { "cats" : 1,  "dogs": 2}
}
```

Where my second function can take a given path lets say `animals.cows` made up using `path+key` and a `value of say 1` and then update this document to the following:

```
{
fruits:  { "apple" : 1, "banana": 2},
animals: { "cats" : 1,  "dogs": 2, "cows":1}
}
```

I was thinking of having a default object with all possible values and somehow re-using that without having to use the hard-coded lists, but unsure if the dictionary data structure for nested dictionaries is the appropriate solution in terms of readability and efficiency.

Comment: The most efficient way to get the "path" is to use a dict and simply look it up directly.  I.e. `{"apple" : "fruits", ..., "cats" : "animals", ...}`

Comment: Hmm that would work, I might have been over thinking to find a more efficient data structure to prevent the number of entries needed in the dictionary in this case we'd need a key for each corresponding schema association

Comment: You can construct the dict dynamically - it doesn't have to be fixed.